# Problem with map tiles loading with Leaflet and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bootstrap-framework

I want to create website with Leaflet map placed in bootstap tab. If I switch into tab where is Leaflet instantion tiles are not loading correct(I see the grey background). I guess there is a problem with size of a  because if resize the browsers window tiles load correctly. Any ideas?
Here is my basic concept.

https://jsfiddle.net/rjper9nz/6/

Comment: See [Data-toggle tab does not download Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map/36257493#36257493) on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Your map's tiles have to be realoaded, which can be done with the method *invalidateSize*:

```
map.invalidateSize();
```

Which is not sufficient to solve the issue because firing this method right at the beginning does not have any effect.

You only want to fire it *after* the tab container has loaded, so you need to know *when* that happens.

The following code does that and fixes your issue:

```
 $("a[href='#menu1']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
      map.invalidateSize();
 });
```

PS: I have renamed your variable *mymap* to *map*, because most people looking this up will call it *map*, so make sure to change that.

Comment: I have `reference not defined` for `map` at the point I show the container. How to get `map`?

Comment: *map* is the map variable, as in *var map = L.map(...*. So, whatever you called your map variable you need to add where I put *map*.

Comment: *map.invalidateSize()*  worked for me. I was having problems refreshing the tiles after I applied the style *display: none;* to the `map` element and then restoring it to *display: block* . According the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-invalidatesize):  "Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so".